# Comparing statements about classes of functions

Tags: functions

Fix sets $A, B, X$, where $B \subset A$. Compare two statements:

**Theorem 1.** For all functions $f : A \to X$, if $f$ satisfies properties $\pi_1,...,\pi_k$, then $f$ satisfies property $\pi_{k+1}$.

**Theorem 2.** For all functions $g : B \to X$, if $g$ satisfies properties $\pi_1,...,\pi_k$, then $g$ satisfies property $\pi_{k+1}$.

The key question is: *does either theorem imply the other*?

It is clear to me that $\{f : A \to X\} \subset \{g : B \to X\}$, because $f$ maps all elements of $B$ to $X$ but $g$ need not map all elements of $A$ to $X$. Indeed, universal domain (the axiom that $h(y)$ is defined for all $y$ in the domain in $h$) is a **restriction** on $h$.

However it is not clear that $\{f : A \to X \mid f \text{ satisfies } \pi_1,...,\pi_k \} \subset \{g : B \to X \mid g \text{ satisfies } \pi_1,...,\pi_k \}$: that should depend on what properties these functions satisfy.

Therefore neither of the two implies the other. Am I correct?

Comment: if F is the set of all functions $f:A\to X$ meeting some criteria and $G$ is the set of all functions $g:B\to X$ meeting the same criteria.  And $B\subset A$ then $G\subset F$

Comment: Can you explain? How can we be sure that $g(a)$ is defined for all $a \in A$?

Comment: Edited my question! (fixed)

Comment: $\{f : A \to X\}$ is commonly denoted by $X^A$. It may not be considered as a *subset* of $X^B$. There is only a natural map $X^A\to X^B:\,f\mapsto f_{|B}$ (the operation of restriction). Hence the question whether $\{f : A \to X \mid f \text{ satisfies } \pi_1,...,\pi_k \} \subset \{g : B \to X \mid g \text{ satisfies } \pi_1,...,\pi_k \}$ or not is inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A,X$ be sets of 2 elements and $B\subset A$ be a singleton.

Theorem 1 $\not\Rightarrow$ Theorem 2: $\forall f\in X^A$, if $f$ is injective then $f$ is bijective, but $\exists g\in X^B$, $g$ is injective and not bijective.

Theorem 2 $\not\Rightarrow$ Theorem 1: $\forall g\in X^B$, $g$ is injective, but $\exists f\in X^A$, $f$ is not injective.

Comment: In my second counterexample, where $\pi_{k+1}$ is "to be injective", the missing $\pi_1,\dots,\pi_k$ are implicitely "True" (or any of your prefered tautology).

Answer (score 0):

Consider, $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous functions. We know that continuous functions on closed sets attains a max and min values.
But clearly $g:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous functions may or may not have that property.

On the other hand, $f:\{1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous functions are constant functions. Clearly $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous functions may or may not be constants.

Comment: Thank you! So in my formulation, neither implies the other, correct?

Comment: This is not strictly speaking an answer to your question, because it handles topological spaces instead of pure sets, and $(a,b)$ is not simply a *subset* of $[a,b]$: it inherits an induced topology. Similarly, $\{1\}$ is not simply a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes neither implies the other

Comment: (followup of my criticism) However, your second counterexample may be easily converted to a "pure set-theoretic" one, by forgetting about topologies and continuity, and just talking about functions which are constant or not.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah I agree thanks for the addition I posted what comes into my mind when the OP mentioned functions  which is calculus :)